# How to reduce a LVM partition without any kind of data loss from the partition without taking any backup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, rhel, lvm

1. A 10 GB partition contains 5 GB data.
2. This partition should be reduced to 8 GB
3. No backup

Comment: absolutely no process that imply to move data between two disk sectors are safe. the easiest way is to have another disk with the right amount of disk on it and do a copy. Shrinking partition is usually no big deal, but if your disk is more than 80% full after shrink you take some risks

Comment: fact is, if you don't take a backup, no matter what answers you receive that may/may not work, there's always a possibility of data corruption when resizing. Particularly so when shrinking. Strongly recommend you take a backup nonetheless.

Answer (score 6):

The following is as safe as you’ll get without backups (*i.e.* quite safe, barring bugs or power failures at the wrong time, and even the latter aren’t necessarily disastrous):

1. Unmount the volume.
2. Resize the logical volume along with the file system it contains:

   ```
   lvresize -r -L8G /path/to/lv
   ```

   The `-r` option ensures that the file system is correctly resized *before* the LV is shrunk, so that the dropped extents are really unused; if anything fails during the file system resize, the LV won’t be resized.
3. Cry if anything goes wrong and you lose data.

I highly recommend backups though, but not specifically for disk operations: any data you care about should be backed up (and restored, if only to verify that it can be restored).

Comment: don't you have to do `resize2fs` after ?

Comment: :)  :) :) ......Actually i need to know about any proper method for that...or let me know is it possible or not.

Comment: @Kiwy Actually you have to do that **before**.  But the `-r` flag already takes care of shrinking the filesystem.

Comment: @Kiwy the `-r` flag takes care of that, as dr01 mentions above, and will stop the whole process if the file system resize fails (*e.g.* because there’s too much data). When shrinking, `-r` will resize the file system before shrinking the volume; when enlarging, `-r` will resize the file system after enlarging the volume.

Comment: Did the LVM arrange the allocated PE's before shrinking or they simply shrink it??

Comment: @Jibin the file system resize operation ensures only the first 8GiB’s worth of PEs are used (which corresponds to your “PE re-arrangement”); then the LV resize reduces the number of allocated PEs and moves the meta-data if necessary.

Comment: @StephenKitt Amazing information... I like it and never used it before...

Comment: @Kiwy the nice thing about `-r` is that it supports any file system handled by `fsadm` (currently, ext2/3/4, ReiserFS and XFS), which makes things much simpler for a site such as this one — there’s less need to ask what file system people are using ;-).

Comment: As the OP asked for Ubuntu Centos .... I doubt he have lvm though. I think default ubuntu install doesn't do LVM.

Comment: @Kiwy Furthermore some filesystems cannot be reduced online, xfs for instance.